# facebook php sdk v5 get Access Token

Tags: php, facebook, token

I want to get the user data of facebook.

I´m using a this example :

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'APP_ID',
  'app_secret' => 'APP_SECRET',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$permissions = ['email']; // optional

try {
    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
        $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
    } else {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    }
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();

    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
 }

if (isset($accessToken)) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    } else {
        // getting short-lived access token
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

        // OAuth 2.0 client handler
        $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

        // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
        $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);

        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;

        // setting default access token to be used in script
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    }

    // redirect the user back to the same page if it has "code" GET variable
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        header('Location: ./');
    }

    // getting basic info about user
    try {
        $profile_request = $fb->get('/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email');
        $profile = $profile_request->getGraphNode()->asArray();
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        session_destroy();
        // redirecting user back to app login page
        header("Location: ./");
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    // printing $profile array on the screen which holds the basic info about user
    print_r($profile);

    // Now you can redirect to another page and use the access token from $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']
} else {
    // replace your website URL same as added in the developers.facebook.com/apps e.g. if you used http instead of https and you used non-www version or www version of your website then you must add the same here
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://sohaibilyas.com/fbapp/', $permissions);
    echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
}
```

In this case, although I am logged in facebook, the first time It always show me "Log in with Facebook!" and it only get the token after redirect. I don´t know it I am doing something wrong, but I would like if the user is logged in Facebook it is not necessary to click in Log in.

Edit, resolves

After writing, I realized that I just needed to do header("location: ".$loginUrl); to avoid click in the link.

Comment: Being logged in to Facebook, and being logged in to your specific app are two different things.

Comment: Is it in the new PHP Api Version? I believe that in old versions, I can get datauser if is logged in the browser

Comment: No, there is nothing new about this. The JS SDK is able to automatically recognize users that have logged in to your app before - because it can make cross-domain requests in the background to check with Facebook. But using the pure server-side login flow, you need to send the user to the login dialog URL first to be able to determine that.

Comment: It was very easy I wanted to do I only need header("location: ".$loginUrl); to avoid the user click in the link. Thanks for your time.

Comment: That is not really a good idea. First of all, it is likely to deter new users, who have no idea what your app is about. Secondly, if users decline login and you send them straight back to the login dialog _again_, Facebook will notice and redirect the user away from your app, to a page asking them to _report_ this app behavior. If you want users that logged in to your app before to get logged in automatically when they visit your site again - then use the JS SDK for that. It works hand in hand with the PHP SDK.

Comment: It is not a "public application", the user only can access by invitation and they now that login in facebook is necesary, But I'll think about what you said, thanks